# Android Studio Kotlin Recyclerview how to do multiple type view for specific object feature?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit, cardview

I have data from RickandMorty Api and saving them on CharacterList and I am showing them in a recyclerview.I have name,location and status informations and showing them in cards.I have another carditem for displaying dead users and I want to show Alive persons in default card and Dead persons in another carditem (Default Carditem with blue backgroundcolor and other carditem is with red backgroundcolor).So as my researches people handle that with  getItemViewType() but in my case I want to classify them each object's status type which is Alive or Dead.How can I do it?

Here is my Main Activity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CharacterViewModel::class.java)

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        viewModel.getData()
    }

    viewModel.users.observe(this, Observer { characterList ->
        for (i in characterList.results){
            Log.e(TAG, "${i.name}")
            name_list.add(i.name)
        }
        recyclerview1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerview1.adapter = Adapter(characterList.results)


    })


}}
```

Here is my ViewHolder Class

```
class ViewHolder (container: ViewGroup) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
        //xml deki verilere bakarak arayüz viewvi oluşturuyor
        LayoutInflater.from(container.context).inflate
            (
            R.layout.carditem,
            container,
            false
        )
    ) {
    val crdView: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview1)
    val profileLink: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePhoto)
    val txtname: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name)
    val txtlocation: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location)
    val txtstatus: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status)


    fun bind(characteritem: Result) {
        txtname.text = characteritem.name
        profileLink.load(characteritem.image)
        txtlocation.text = characteritem.location.name
        txtstatus.text=characteritem.status
    }
}
```

And my Adapter class

```
class Adapter(val CharacterList: List<Result>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(parent)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return CharacterList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder,position: Int) {
            holder.bind(CharacterList[position])

    }


}
```

[Here is what I've done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRbjE.png)

[And what I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch778.png)

[The view of Cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9KUq.png)

Comment: Have a look at the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72994172/9473786), although if all you want is to change some text and background color you should just do that with the same view layout in the bind method

Comment: I checked it but still couldn't understand how to use it.In the example there are some class and which function belongs to which class and how to use it, I couldn't understand how to implement to my project.Even I try to override that function in Viewholder class I got the error.

Comment: What are you referring to with "that function"? `getItemViewType`? That goes in the adapter, not the view holder

Comment: Okey I supposed it is in the ViewHolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your different layouts have the same resources, just with different appearance you could just pass an alternate layout ID to your view holder, like this:

```kotlin
class Adapter(val CharacterList: List<Result>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (CharacterList[position].status == "Dead") 0 else 1
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layout = if(viewType == 0) R.layout.card_dead else R.layout.card_alive
        return ViewHolder(parent, layout)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return CharacterList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder,position: Int) {
        holder.bind(CharacterList[position])
    }
}
```

Then modify the view holder to take the layout ID as a constructor input:

```kotlin
class ViewHolder (container: ViewGroup, layout: Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(container.context).inflate
        (
            layout,
            container,
            false
        )
    ) 
{
    //...
}
```

Alternately you could just use a single layout and change the background color programmatically in `bind`

Comment: I tried that but all of them convert to blue or red.I mean it is still same.

Comment: Show what you tried (adapter and view holder code) - this works. Are you sure you made all the changes I listed here?

Comment: Yeah I treid I changed the codes you have given.Only CharacterList[position].isDead is different cause I use it like CharacterList[position].equals("Alive") but other things are same.

Comment: That looks wrong, you are comparing the character object to "Alive", not an attribute of the class. How is the `Result` class defined?

Comment: Yeah but can't I compare it with that way?

Comment: Does your Result class have some attribute that indicates if it is alive?

Comment: No It is like this for each character
https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/814

Comment: Try `CharacterList[position].status == "Dead"`. It looks like the status field indicates if they are dead. If your Result class doesn't have a status field, you need to add it so it can populate it from the json

Comment: Also, if you want to test that the layout stuff works you could use something like `return if(position>3) 0 else 1` in `getItemViewType`. It should make some red and some blue

Comment: Okey i will try it when i arrive to home from internship.And Thanks for help

Comment: CharacterList[position].status == "Dead" is worked.But I tried that before .contains.It wouldn't work firstly but now it worked I couldn't understand why it didn't work.Anyways Thanks for help I really get what I need.

Comment: Probably I was trying to equals instead contains.I was really tired yesterday so I couldn't notice what i did.

Answer (score -1):

In your adapter, override `getItemViewType` like this.

```
@Override
fun getItemViewType(position:Integer):Integer {
    return if (CharacterList[position].isDead) 0 else 1
}
```

Then in the `onCreateViewHolder` check the `viewType` to know if you need to create a view for 'alive' or 'dead'.

Comment: Yeah I override that function but I don't know how to check viewtype in viewholder because viewholder declaration is in the scope.

Comment: Your answer is a mix of Java and Kotlin syntax...

Comment: @CSS the viewType returned from getItemViewType is passed into the onCreateViewHolder method as the viewType parameter.

Comment: Yeah with that method it worked.

Comment: I didn't vote by the way